# (Closure) Axiom necesarry to solve Protégé Ontology issue?

Tags: owl, protege

I am currently working on a ontology.
I created a bunch of individuals (every individual should be sorted to a different optimization problem like TSP, VRP and VRPTW).
But I think the open world assumption creates some problems.

In Individuals I want the reasoner to realize that Auftrag 1 is a TSP, Auftrag 2 is a VRP and Auftrag 3 a VRPTW. At the moment it works
but only because for 1 and 2 I use the "exactly" cardinality in types.
I have to do this because if not the reasoner may think that there could be more than one of this kind (in this example warehouse or simpleVehicle).

Because of that I created this "exactly 1" cardinality on types so that the reasoner can only sort it right. But as soon as I am right the closure axiom could help me so to prevent the open world assumption at this point?

I hope you understand my point.

I attached the file, best regards!

File:
https://www2.zippyshare.com/v/loP7YJNP/file.html

Comment: Is this a spam link? Downloads a `.exe` for me.

Comment: Hmm.. The download now button downloads the actual .owl file. 
I created a second link:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-13330664/projectOP.owl.html

Comment: Your TSP is defined as `(hasNode min 2 Node) and (hasVehicle exactly 1 SimpleVehicle) and (hasWarehouse exactly 1 Warehouse)` . It will not work to classify `Auftrag1` as TSP just based on the ABox axioms because exact cardinality suffers fro mthe Open World Assumption. Indeed, what you did works, i.e. asserting `Auftrag1` as `(hasNode min 2 Node) and (hasVehicle exactly 1 SimpleVehicle) and (hasWarehouse exactly 1 Warehouse)` - but what is the question now? And what is a "closure axiom"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I find this solution to be a bit rough. As soon as I am correctly informed the closure axiom (pattern) allows to prevent the ontology on that point to make use of the open world assumption. But to make it more simple - My question ist: Is there another possibility to solve this problem without using the exactly 1 cardinalities? I though that there should be a a more smooth way than my approach.. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I strongly suggest you use custom inference rules to implement domain rules.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by that?